# clojurescript undeclared Var goog.structs/Map

Tags: clojurescript

I have added a library into my project and now I am getting this error

`clojurescript undeclared Var goog.structs/Map`

This is the library : `https://github.com/ptaoussanis/tempura/blob/master/src/taoensso/`

Comment: Can you describe more things about your project? Which libraries are already in the project? How are you compiling it? Can you provide a snippet of your code? Please edit your question above to add those details so other users can help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue, to be fixed at some point, but can be safely ignored:

https://github.com/ptaoussanis/timbre/issues/305

If you don't want to ignore it, add the newest version of the underlying com.taoensso/encore library to your dependencies; either:

- as `[com.taoensso/encore "2.117.0"]` into `project.clj` if you're using leiningen, or
- as `{com.taoensso/encore {:mvn/version "2.117.0"}` if you're using tools.deps.

This will force the encore version to resolve to the newest one, and ignore the version the tempura library has declared.

https://github.com/ptaoussanis/tempura/issues/29#issuecomment-557178091